# rsolnp equality constraint not satisfied

Tags: r, constraints

Why does rsolnp not satisfy my equality constraint?

```
require(Rsolnp)
f=function(p){sum(p*log(p))}
g=function(p){sum(p)-1}
p0=runif(10)
p0=p0/sum(p0)
res=solnp(p0,f,g)
print(g(res$par))
```

returns

```
[1] 2.678794
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `eqB` argument of `solnp`:

```
res <- solnp(p0, fun=f, eqfun=g, eqB=0)

res$pars
# [1] 0.09999172 0.09999483 0.10000076 0.09999327 0.09999380 
#     0.10000139 0.10000720 0.09999597 0.10000309 0.10001796

print(g(res$pars))
# [1] 2.464695e-14
```

Comment: missed that out. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MichaelMoos OK, nice to help you. Please, accept my answer and close the question. Thank you.